# Segfault when running doctrine:migrations:status in prod, after switching to php7

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, php-7, doctrine-migrations

Running:

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:status --env=prod
```

gives me a Segfault, but only in prod, and only after the cache has been populated. So after clearing the cache the command runs fine. However, the second time the command is ran, I get the Segfault.

I run the most recent version of `doctrine/migrations`, Symfony 2.7.4, and PHP7.0.0 with APCU enabled.

The issue started manifesting itself after switching to PHP7. I am experiencing the same issue, both on my Mac (el capitan) as on Ubuntu server (14.04).

Is anyone experiencing similar issues?

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance of a log excerpt?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was an issue with Monolog's Swift handler. Updating the Monolog bundle resolved the issue